# Ubuntu 16.10 Installation Error

Tags: 16.04, grub2, windows-10

I have been trying to install ubuntu 16.10 for about a week now, and I keep getting the same error message "Executing grub-install /dev/sda failed fatal error" I have shrank the windows partition by about 20 gigs, turned fast boot and secure boot off (I'm using windows 10 by the way). I would like to keep windows and install ubuntu alongside it. I am booting from a bootable usb with the iso on it. It does launch into ubuntu, but the installer always crashes towards the end with the fore mentioned error message. Not sure what to do next. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Oh, the laptop is a new dell inspiron with an i7 skylake processor, 8 gigs of ddr4 ram. and a single 1tb HDD. If you need any more information, please let me know.

Comment: Same issue here but with a dell xps 15 9550.